# How to retrieve Json error from Zuul Filter

Tags: json, netflix-zuul

I am using Postman to send a request to the Zuul proxy. Zuul proxy is running on the `port 8085` 
(http://localhost:8085/helloworld)

I am having a zuul filter and calling a micro service from the zuul filter using Spring RestTemplate. Micro service is running on 8089

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        "http://localhost:8089/helloworld", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

When I get a successful response from the microservice, I am receiving a successful JSON object response in Postman.

But when an error/exception is returned from the microservice, the zuul filter does not send it back it to the calling client. I am getting an empty body with `httpstatus message 200` in Postman, even though microservice returned a `500 error`.

I tried to send the microservice response using

```
ctx.setResponseBody(response.getBody());
```

Basically this will convert the JSON response from the micro service into a String. I was able to get the response as a String object in the Postman.

Could anyone help me how to get the error/exception response as JSON object from the Zuul filter.